# Given a family of probability distributions that are "close to each other" and have expected values 1, 2, 3..., find a lower bound on their variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, variance, total-variation

Let $\left(\mathcal{D}_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of probability distributions such as:

- $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathcal{D}_{n}\right]=n$: the average value of the n-th distribution is n.
- $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\delta\left(\mathcal{D}_{n},\mathcal{D}_{n+1}\right)<\varepsilon$
  for some small $\varepsilon>0$, where $\delta$ is the [total variation
  distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures):
  two consecutive distributions are "close to each other".

I want to find a lower bound on $\text{Var}\left(\mathcal{D}_{n}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mathcal{D}_{n}-n\right)^{2}\right]$.

[Edit: I originally conjectured that the bound was something like $\frac{\left(1-\varepsilon\right)}{\varepsilon}\cdot n$, at least asymptotically, but Ross' answer below shows that this is wrong and you can get a family for which each variance is proportional to $1/\varepsilon^2$. I'm looking for any lower bound that is proportional to $1/\varepsilon$ for small values of $\varepsilon$.]

Answer (score 3):

You can have the variance independent of $n$.  Let each $\mathcal{D}_{n}$ be a triangular distribution that starts at $n-k$ with value $\varepsilon$, rises in steps of $\varepsilon$ up to $(k+1)\varepsilon$ at $n$, then drops back down to $\varepsilon$ at $n+k$.  This set of distributions satisfies the distance requirement.  To get total probability of $1$ we need $k+1=\frac 1{\sqrt {\varepsilon}}$.  The variance is $$2\sum_{j=1}^k(k-j)\epsilon j^2\approx \frac 1{6\varepsilon}$$ I haven't proved this is the minimum

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. For the problem that I'm studying that led me to this question, a lower bound of the form $1/\varepsilon$ (up to some multiplicative constant) would be good enough.

Comment: If I understand total variation distance correctly, the OP's $\varepsilon$ is defined as for _events_, not individual instances.  For the triangular distributions here, I think the worst case event is $\mathcal{D} \le n$, and the distance for that event is $|P(\mathcal{D}_n \le n) - P(\mathcal{D}_{n+1} \le n)| = (k+1)\epsilon = \sqrt{\epsilon}$, so you need to set $\sqrt{\epsilon} = \varepsilon$ or $\epsilon = \varepsilon^2$.  The variance is then $\propto 1/\varepsilon^2$...  is that still good enough?

Comment: @antkam:  as I read the definition it was the maximum difference between the probabilities of individual instances.  Maybe OP will clarify.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but a more careful read of the wikipedia article quoted in the OP clearly said event...

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, which was wrong. Yes, I'm talking about the total variation distance as defined on the Wikipedia page (or, equivalently up to a factor of $2$, $\left\Vert \mathcal{D}_{n}-\mathcal{D}_{n+1}\right\Vert _{1}$). So Ross' answer doesn't satisfy the constraint, as antkam pointed out. I need a lower bound proportional to $1/\varepsilon$, so $1/\varepsilon^2$ would also be good enough.